# Can I change the dot to a colon after Proof in amsthm?

Tags: environments, amsthm, proof-package

I want to write `Proof:` in front of a proof instead of `Proof.` How may I achieve this?

Here is a MWE for the set up I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`amsthm` uses `\@addpunct{.}` to put the period. You can patch the `\proof` using `xpatch` to replace dot by `:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{:}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want upright `:` use this:

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\@addpunct{.}}{\normalfont\,\@addpunct{:}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `\nopunct`? This is the official way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Proof:\nopunct]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a upright $:$ this way?

Comment: Of course, just use something like `\textup`.

Answer (score 2):

From page 11 of the documentation. You can use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item\relax
{\itshape
#1\@addpunct{:}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Here comes the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```