# Can I eliminate the dot after Theorem in amsthm?

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm

Instead of *1 Theorem.* I want to write *1 Theorem* in front of the first theorem and analogously in front of succeeding theorems. How can I get rid of the dot?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the dot to a colon after Proof in amsthm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268912/can-i-change-the-dot-to-a-colon-after-proof-in-amsthm)

Comment: replace the `\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{:}}{}{}` by `\xpatchcmd{\theorem}{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{}}{}{}` should do the trick

Comment: @RomainPicot: It won't work. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I've seen your answer  after `;-)`

Comment: @Romain Picot My question here does not duplicate the question I asked earlier, so please unmark it as a possible duplicate. Harish Kumar's answer here is quite to the point and I accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now patch `@thm` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]