# How to change dot to colon after theorem in amsthm?

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm

How do I change the dot to a colon in a theorem environment?

Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{test}{Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

Not a duplicate of
[Can I change the dot to a colon after Proof in amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268912/can-i-change-the-dot-to-a-colon-after-proof-in-amsthm)
since neither answers there work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{colon}%
{}
{}
{\itshape}%bodyfont
{}%indent
{\bfseries}%headfont
{:}%head punctuation
{ }%space after head
{}

\theoremstyle{colon}
\newtheorem*{test}{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
Blah blah blah.
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new theorem style like this:

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% name of the style to be used
  {}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {}% measure of space to indent
  {}% name of head font
  {:}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
```

Just add this before the first use of \newtheorem.

Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems