# Proof structure in latex

Tags: mathematics

I am making my own definition for proof with the problem that the text is being displayed in italics.  This is because `\begin{lexproof}` is being called within `\begin{theorem}`.

```
\newenvironment{lexproof}
   {
     \paragraph{Proof:}
   }
   {\hfill \textdagger}


\newpage
\section{Pythagoreas} 

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
   A theorem about right triangles summarised by the equation
   \[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]

   \begin{lexproof}
      To prove it by contradiction try and assume that the statement i s
      false, proceed from there and at some point you will arrive to a
      contradiction.
   \end{lexproof}

\end{theorem}
```

Comment: The [amsthm package](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm?lang=en) (`\usepackage{amsthm}`) defines one, and also provides nice ways of defining new theorem-like environments generally.

Comment: Am having a go for my own based on `amsthm`.  Picking up some of the code.  What could I try.  The original has lot of calls,

Comment: There's nothing in your example that mentions italic, so it's impossible to say why that might be happening.  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268912) provides several methods to have a colon after `proof` starting with `amsthm`.  And changing the default box to a dagger can be done with `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\textdagger}`.

Comment: Usually, the proof comes after the theorem and is separate from it.

Comment: You've changed the question so now my first comment makes no sense. Sigh. Don't do that. Anyway the default theorem style puts its contents in italics, if that's what you mean. You can use definition style instead for no italics. Use `\theoremstyle{definition}` before `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` if you don't want italics. And maybe start reading [documentation](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) rather than asking a new question here every hour?

Comment: `\paragraph` is a level 4 section heading following section subsection and subsubsection, do not use it in a theorem

Comment: @Randy There are reasons why the `amsthm` definition of `proof` seems complicated, the main one being that typesetting a proof *is* a complex task. Don't try reinventing the wheel.